# Story about "entity" and his partner taking over human bodies

Tags: story-identification

I admit I don't really remember much about the story since I read it in the early '90s.
I read it in Italian.

The only thing I can remember is that this "entities" or gods reincarnate/take over the bodies of a couple of adults. If I don't remember wrong this couple was living in a hut in the forest (farmers or lumberjack).

The two then start exploring the world (flying or teleportation?) and enjoying their new bodies.

It may be part of a series as I remember there being indication of a backstory or that the "entity" was already known to the reader.